# Mcafee hangs on "Checking for updates" in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

It was not happening before on `Windows 10` but in the past few days whenever I check for Updates on `McAfee` it just shows the following message box but it never completes even after running it for many hours. It happens even if I close all the programs and/or restart my Toshiba laptop. **Note**: Not sure if it's related or not, but the issue started after Microsoft Windows regular Monthly updates were installed. I have set Windows Update option to auto update.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue

Comment: @Ramhound Then, what you would think could be a possible remedy?